# Swift custom cells layout TableView decision

Tags: ios, swift2

I need to display a table with in my iPhone app:

> neither the number of cells nor the contents are known at compile time, but only at run time.

Views for each cell may differ, one cell has textField and another may have some other view control.

Should I consider Static or prototype cells?
Should I consider tableViewController or viewController with tableview in it?

Any thing I need to consider before I start coding? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can use static tableview and tableviewcontroller instead of view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I consider Static or prototype cells?

If you know all possible subview combinations that your cells might need to display the data appropriately, and they are relatively few, make one prototype for each. for example:

1. One text field,
2. Two labels,
3. One image view and a label,

...etc.

Otherwise, just use the plain-vanilla `UITableViewCell` (no subclassing) and remove/add subviews at runtime when reusing them (that is, inside the method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`).

> Should I consider tableViewController or viewController with tableview
>   in it?

The **only** reason I would choose `UIViewController` + `UITableView` over `UITableViewController` is if -for example- I needed the table view to only take up *part* of the main view's bounds/screen, and display some other subview in the remainder. Otherwise, you get so much "for free" with `UITableViewController` that there's just no point in implementing all of that from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

- For The issue of dynamic Number of cell at Run time, you can call reload data for table view at any time you have the data source ready.
- Prototype Cells should be used with no problem.
- Simple Table View will be sufficient for the task.
- You have to make cell, either in code or in storyboard, for each type of cell you want, 1 table View can have multiple types of prototype cells, Just name them differently and then make the objects of only the specific cell of which the data is best suited.
- It is not that difficult but do handle the data source with extreme care.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose prototype cell, u can create different types of cell depending upon your requirement.Any think ok for u, u can create tableview controller or view controller.